# sqlite append two tables from two databases that have the exact same schema

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing data into an sqlite database, but because the data set is very large, I'm splitting the process into five pieces. As a result, I'm writing to five different sqlite databases at the same time, each having the same column names, and in the end, I want to append the five tables in the five databases together into one table. What is the way to do this?

Comment: see also [SQLite Shared-Schema Mode](https://sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/reuse-schema/doc/shared_schema.md)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to make the contents of another database file accessible in the same connection:

```
ATTACH "/some/where/db2.sqlite" AS db2;
INSERT INTO main.MyTable SELECT * FROM db2.MyTable;
```

(The main database is always called `main`; opening a new database connection is the equivalent of `ATTACH "filename" AS main`.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use **UNION** or **UNION ALL** to merge 2 or more queries.

Something like:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Table2
```

You can use an `INSERT INTO NewTableName (SELECT ...)` to create a new table from that UNION.

The **ALL** variant of the **UNION** clause includes the (eventual) duplicate records.