# Copying column from one database to another

Tags: database, sqlite

I have 2 databases. One called 'main' and the other 'AM.'
main and AM have the same table structure. They both have a table called 'values'. Both tables have the same number of rows and columns. 
I am trying to perform the following command

```
sqlite> insert into main.values(name) select name from AM.values;
```

but I obtain the following error:

```
Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: values.guid
```

Name and guid are names of columns in both tables. Can anyone advise on why this error is occurring? My insert command does not involve the guid column, and only involves the name column, but error points to an issue with the guid column.

Comment: INSERT creates new rows. Is that what you want?

Comment: Try this, it may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292367/sqlite-append-two-tables-from-two-databases-that-have-the-exact-same-schema

Comment: @CL. Oh.... I thought insert can be used to replace. Wow. What is the command to replace existing rows then?

Comment: @Anup This seems to be for appending to the end of the existing table?

Comment: Do you really want to replace entire rows, or just to UPDATE one column? And SQL tables are unordered; how should the database find the corresponding row in the other table?

Comment: @lawson Error is occurring bcz field guid is defined Not Null, it means "The NOT NULL constraint enforces a column to NOT accept NULL values and u r going to insert record without guid col". So u can remove the NOT NULL constraint from guid col or insert value in guid as well.